# CKEDITOR does not work when i send the data

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, laravel-livewire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrQDi.png)hello to all I have installed ckeditor via the cdn for my textarea. this during when I launch for the validation or/and the saving of data, my textarea returns me obligatory fields.
I've been scouring the net to see how to do it since then.
I use laravel 8 and laravel livewire.
enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Gpz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ5bW.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is that you're having. Could you add some context to the question?

Comment: I just added content to better understand

Comment: Hi Palingrima! When you are posting a question, we expect you to provide some code snippets to support your question. Using screenshots is not something we can help you easily with. So can you please elaborate or restate your actual question? Cheers!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't so expressive in my question. I rephrase then and my apologies.
Indeed I am on laravel 8 and I code with livewire and alpine js (Beginner). I was creating a form to make posts. in my form I have a triter a category and a description. It is in my description that I have implemented summernote as richtext. when we load the creation page, my richtext is displayed without any problems. but when I click on the save button of the form, the richtext disappears and shows me an error.

Comment: Ckeditor and summernote which I use. but none of them work.